# systemd: solution for stampede effect when restarting multiple services?

Tags: systemd

I have a `systemd` target that has about 100 child services. If I restart an individual child service, it starts up in just a few seconds.

However, if I restart all 100 child services at once, all the CPU cores get slammed, the load goes up to 50, and the services remain offline for 30 seconds or more as the children all fight for CPU resources to boot up.

One solution to solve this is to script a rolling restart: Find all the child services and restart them one by one with a three second pause between them. This allows all the children to come up quickly but is increasingly slow as new child services are added.

Is there is another way to prevent the stampede effect with systemd? I thought perhaps the right kind CPU throtting might prevent any one child from using CPU, allowing the services to restart efficient without significant downtime or artificial pauses.

Also, I don't want to set up a dependency chain with systemd: All the child services currently share the same systemd template.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a `CPUWeight=80` directive to my template service but it seems to make little difference. What did work was creating a `big-restartall.service`calls a simple bash script which contains logic for a simple, rolling restart. In my case, I found a one second pause between each service was sufficient to avoid the stampede affect, keeping start times and load low during the process.

```bsh
# Restart the children of "big.target". 
for service in $(systemctl list-dependencies --plain big.target | grep -v target); {
  systemctl restart $service;
  # Give those processes a chance to start-- avoid a stampede effect.
  sleep 1;
}
```